# GS202: Threshold needs to be greater than 0

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm using the protocol kit of Safe{Wallet}, and I want to remove a wallet owner.
My code is the next one:

```
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter,
        safeAddress: userSafeAddress
    })  

    const newThreshold = 1

    //Remove an owner
    const removeOwnerTxParams = {
        ownerAddress,
        newThreshold
    }

    const tx = await safeSdk.createRemoveOwnerTx(removeOwnerTxParams)
    const txResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(tx)
    await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait()
```

But I'm getting the next error after executing this code: **Error: Threshold needs to be greater than 0**

The wallet currently has two owners, and the threshold is 1, so I just want to remove an owner and keep the threshold.